# How to print odd numbers in this range, am getting all the numbers even though incrementing by 2?

Tags: python

My code is not giving the desired result, I want to add odd numbers from 1 to 10 to this list one by one but it is adding them all.

```
    l=[]
    for i in range(1,10):
        l.append(i)
        i=i+2
    print(l)
```

I want to store 1,3,5,7,9 in the list.

Comment: `for i in range(a,b,step):` where step in your case could be 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators in python can not be dynamically changed inside the for loop body. Modifying the current value does not affect what appears next in the iteration.

So if you want to print odd numbers, you should use built-in step size argument like this

```
l=[]
for i in range(1, 10, 2):
    l.append(i)
print(l)
```

Here we are using step size of 2 to increment the iterable by 2 after every iteration.

Comment: No need of `i=i+2`

Comment: You don't need to use `i=i+2` as it will be incremented in range only.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to remove that line after editing his code lol, thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys, moving to python from c++ is not that simple I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inline for loop as follows

```
l = [i for i in range(1, 10) if i%2==1]
print(l)
# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

or using step argument for range function

```
l = [i for i in range(1, 10,2)]
print(l)
# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python the simplest way to achieve what you want is:

```
l = list(range(1, 10, 2))
print(l)
```

For your code, the simplest fix would be to just add the step-size argument

```
    l=[]
for i in range(1,10,2):
    l.append(i)
    i=i+2
print(l)
```